# replace the Kth value in the order of the list of identifiers, with the given identifier

Tags: c, list, identifier

A list of identifiers is given. The length of each identifier is no more than 8 characters. Identifiers in the list are indicated in lexicographical order. Compose a function for the following operation: replace the kth value in the order of the list of identifiers with the given identifier. 
I can't make it work, after I type what element it should be replace with, it just skips pech_sp and goes to the line below it. Here's the code:

```
struct el_sp             
  {  char  id [MAXDL];     
     struct el_sp *sled;   
  };
int replace(struct el_sp *p, int k, char *str)
{
    struct el_sp *pt;
    int i;
    pt = p;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        if (pt->sled != NULL)
            pt = pt->sled;
        else {
            printf("...");
            break;
        }
    }
    strncpy_s(pt->id, str, MAXDL);
    return (0);
}
void  vkl(struct el_sp **p, char t_id[] )  
{  struct el_sp  * pt,      
                  *k,*j = NULL;    
    pt = (struct el_sp *)malloc(sizeof(struct el_sp));
    strcpy_s(pt->id,t_id);
    if (*p==NULL || strcmp(pt->id,(*p)->id)<0)
       {   
         pt->sled=*p; *p=pt;
       }
    else
       {k=*p;
         while (k!=NULL && strcmp(pt->id,k->id)>=0)
         { j=k; k=k->sled; 
         }
         j->sled=pt; pt->sled=k;
       }
  }

void pech_sp(struct el_sp *p )
   { struct el_sp *i; 
     printf("\Result:\n");
     for( i=p; i!=NULL; i=i->sled )
         puts (i->id);
   }
int main(){
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    struct el_sp  *p;    
    unsigned  n;        
    unsigned  i;
    unsigned  k;
    char *r;
    char t_id[MAXDL];    

    printf("\nEnter the amount of identifiers\n n=");
    scanf_s("%u",&n);
    getchar();   
    p=NULL;      
    printf("Enter the identifier ");
    printf("(after each identifier press <Enter> )\n");
    for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ )
       { gets_s(t_id);
         vkl (&p,t_id);  
       }
    pech_sp(p);
    printf("Which identifier should be replaced?:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    printf("\nWhat should it be replaced with?:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &r);
    replace(p, k, r);
    pech_sp(p);
    printf("\n\nTo finish, press any key\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Dude at least format your code before you ask for help. This literally looks like it was intentionally obfuscated.

Comment: @Dani Ali The variable r is declared like char *r; It is an uninitialized pointer. You are trying to read  an integer using this pointer printf("\nWhat should it be replaced with?:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &r); This does not make sense.

Comment: How was the code compiled?  Since `p` isn't used for a while after enter values, the optimizer might have simply moved some things around.  Are you sure you are debugging code that is compiled for debug?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Dude, thank you so much, I didn't even notice I was inputting an integer, when it should be a character. I passed it as a pointer into replace and made it into r instead *r and it works now.